# iphone/ipad: how to incorporate flash animation in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash, ipad

I'd like to incoporate some flash animation (a 2d character animation) into
my objective c app.

I heard you can create and export a flash cs5 app into iphone. But
I don't want to export an entire app. Just a small component...

for example, I want to get an animation of a 2d character waving that
was made in flash and just incorporate that into my 
objective c app. Can this be done?

Comment: Have you found a workflow that works for you, @foreyez? I just asked a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330161/thoughts-on-workflow-of-non-scripted-animated-scenes

Answer (score 0):

If it's really that simple of an animation, it would probably be best to go with an image sequence. You can create a UIImageView and set the animationImages property as an array of UIImage objects.

Another alternative would be to use one of the Flash to HTML5 conversion tools and include a UIWebView in your app.

Answer (score 0):

i think that exporting a flash cs5 application into an iphone application has nothing to do with objective c. it is an independent process. you cannot merge both processes and export a flash component to your obj-c application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any supported ways of getting Flash content onto a iPhone or other iOS device.  [Apple doesn't want Flash on the iPhone](http://www.businessinsider.com/adobe-gives-in-to-apple-releases-flash-to-html-converter-2011-3).

Adobe has released an experimental tool called [Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/) that can export Flash files (.FLA) into HTML5, so perhaps you could use a UIWebView to load that content?

UIWebView will also support [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) on the iPhone, so if you can convert your source material to SVG, that might also work.  Many vector animation tools will export to SVG.

Finally, you could code your animation by hand using Core Graphics and Quartz, but that might be painful for anything but the most simple animations.